# Why pegjs not match Expression when __ not matched? Program = __/Expression

Tags: pegjs

**Example code:**

```
Program = __/Expression

Expression = .*

__ = [ \t\r\n]*
test is

2 * (3 + 4)
hahah hahhah
def hahah
```

In my mind , pegjs while match Expression when `__` is not matched?
But this get a error

**Line 1, column 1:** Expected `[ \t\r\n]` or end of input but `"2"` found.
Expected behavior:

I want to know why it is not work.
And I what to know is it possible to get all function callees in js use pegjs?

**Actual behavior:**
A parse error: Line 1, column 1: Expected `[ \t\r\n]` or end of input but `"2"` found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you rule __ always matched, because it match empty input. You can think, that you grammar internally rewriten as follow (this is perfectly valid grammar, you can input it in pegjs online):

```
start = Program EOF

Program = __/Expression

Expression = .*

__ = [ \t\r\n]*
// EOF is ephemeral rule that match end of input, i.e. when nothing left in input
EOF = !.
```

So you input parsed as:

```
<'__' matched>
<'Program' matched>
<'EOF' not matched
  =>backtrack to 'start'
  =>nothing alternatives on 'start'
  =>error
>2 * (3 + 4)
```